# I.click()-selector in CodeceptJS - how to find first button with specific innerHTML

Tags: codeception, codeceptjs

I have various buttons and several buttons with the same name "Start". I need to click on the first found button with this name (innerHTML).
With jQuery this works with :

`$('button:contains(Start):first').click()`

How does it work with I.click()-Selector in CodeceptJS? I can't find the right syntax and always getting:

> "invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified"

Here is the API for this function: https://github.com/Codeception/CodeceptJS/blob/master/docs/webapi/click.mustache

The only working solution I found is:

`I.click('//button[1]');`

But this solution is confusing, because you need to know the exactly number in the order of this element - and I have a lot of buttons with different names. Also this not allows me to search by innerHTML such as "Start".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `I.executeScript` like this:

```
I.executeScript("var elements = document.getElementsByName('Start');elements[0].click();"); or
I.executeScript("var elements = 
document.querySelector(\"button[name*='Start']\");elements[0].click();");
```

Comment: I can't test it anymore because I asked this almost 5 month ago :) But because the other answer didn't work and your answer looks legit, I will accept it.

Comment: @MeteorNewbie Yeah :) May be it will help for someone else

Answer (score 1):

You need using XPath for that

`//button[1][contains(text(), 'Start')]`

Comment: Do I use this function wrong: `I.click("//button[1][contains(text(), 'Start')]");` ? Because I get _" Clickable element //button[1][contains(text(), 'Start')] was not found by text|CSS|XPath"_

Comment: in chrome dev tools on `Elements tab` try `ctrl + f` for `//button[1][contains(text(), 'Start')]`, there you can check search pattern, maybe `Start` should be in lowercase?

Comment: This xpath is an incorrect, because of find some text in first button. Expected result is finding button with some text and getting first node from founded nodes:

```//button[contains(text(), 'Start')][1]```

Answer (score 0):

```js
locate("//button[contains(text(), 'Start')]").first()
```

or

```js
locate("//button[contains(text(), 'Start')]").at(1)
```

Works fine.